# Accessing Objects used to populate DataGridView through DataTable

Tags: c#, events, datagridview, datatable

I am attempting to access the object that is used to fill a DataGridview in this method:

```
void memberDataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in memberDataGridView.SelectedCells)
  {
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in memberDataGridView.Rows)
    {
       if (row.Cells.Contains(cell))
       {
          //here is where I want to access the object that was used to build this row.
          //it will be added as a comboboxitem
       }
  }
}
```

Here is the code of the object being added to the gridview using a DataTable

```
DataRow row = _loadMembersTable.NewRow();
row["Member Name"] = member.InternalLabel;
row["Type"] = member.MemberType;
_loadMembersTable.Rows.Add(row);
memberDataGridView.DataSource = _loadMembersTable;
```

what can I do when building the DataTable to find this member object back when I need it in the selectionChanged?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question properly. I think you are only assigning the object member properties to the data table columns, not the object it self. Therefore you can't directly get the object of type 'member' from the data table.

If you have a collection of members maintained in the memory then, you can query the datatable against `Member Name` column and get then search the collection of the members maintained in the memory.

Or you can add a new column to the DataTable of type member and then add the object to the datatable itself.

To add Column

```
_loadMemebersTable.Columns.Add("MemberObj",typeof(Member));
```

To set values

```
row["MemberObj"] = member;
```